# Finding a total ordering of function growth rates

Tags: real-analysis, set-theory, asymptotics, order-theory

For $f,g:\Bbb R_+\to\Bbb R$, let's define $f<g$ to mean $\exists x_0,\forall x>x_0,f(x)<g(x)$.

Observations about $<$:

- It's finer than the ordering provided by [O-notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation). For example, $x<x+\frac 1x<x+1$.
- If $m:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is increasing, then $m\circ f<m\circ g\iff f<g$. (In contrast, O-notation distinguishes $\exp(x)$ from $\exp(2x)$ but not $x$ from $2x$.)
- If $m:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is increasing and surjective, then $f\mapsto m\circ f$ is an order isomorphism of $<$.
- For any functions $a<b$, the interval $\{f:a<f<b\}$ is order-isomorphic to the whole space of functions (via squeezing $\Bbb R$ into $(a(x),b(x))$ for each $x$). So this order has a lot of symmetry and self-similarity.
- $<$ is not a total order. In fact, for any $f$, we can find an interval of mutually-comparable functions that are all incomparable with $f$, such as $\{g_\alpha:\alpha\in[-1,1]\}$ where $g_\alpha(x)=f(x)+\sin(x)+\alpha$.

To understand the space of limiting behaviors captured by $<$, I'd like to describe a maximal [chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order#Chains) of it.
Beyond maximality, I feel like I should forbid the chain from having "coarse" segments that can be replaced by a larger set of mutually-comparable functions to obtain a "finer" chain. That is, our chain $C$ should have the property that if $(C\setminus X)\cup Y$ is also a chain, then $|X\cap C|\ge|Y\setminus C|$. This implies maximality, so let's call such a chain "finely maximal". (Does this condition seem appropriate? I'm not confident that cardinality is the right tool for the job.)

Then my questions are:

- Is there a finely maximal chain of $<$?
- Are all finely maximal chains order-isomorphic to each other?
- Is there a canonical choice of finely maximal chain? For example, modulo exchanging functions that are eventually identically equal, is there exactly one finely maximal chain of $<$ containing the $0$ function?
- (If yes to any of the above) Is there a simple description of this order structure?

Comment: I think your questions are related the set theory topic [*Hausdorff gaps*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_gap). A nice survey paper is: Marion Scheepers, *Gaps in* ${\omega}^{\omega},$ pp. 439-561 in Haim Judah (editor), [**Set Theory of the Reals**](https://bookstore.ams.org/imcp-6/), Israel Mathematical Conference Proceedings #6,  Bar-Ilan University and American Mathematical Society, 1993, viii + 654 pages.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thanks! I'll check out those sources. It was indeed the "gap" [corresponding to convergent series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2890139) that got me thinking about this order structure again.

Comment: Also of possible interest is Erdős/Rogers/Taylor, [*Scales of functions*](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-the-australian-mathematical-society/issue/EF8AB74AC0199E946B7B5B5BF2FC75AD), **Journal of the Australian Mathematical Society** 1 #4 (December 1960), pp. 396-418.

Comment: I'd also suggest reading about cardinal characteristics of the continuum, as well as generalisations thereof to higher cardinals. Specifically you might be interested to read a bit of Corey Switzer's recent work.

Comment: Related, but about $≪$ rather than $<$: [Every linearly-ordered real-parametrized family of asymptotic classes is nowhere dense?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2607647/21820)

Answer (score 2):

This is only a very partial answer:

It is unclear to me whether there exists a finitely maximal chain but if there is one, I highly doubt that there be a unique one modulo identifying functions that are eventually equal to one another.

Using diagonal definitions of functions, one sees that maximal chains are countably saturated as linear orders. In particular, they are uncountable, and any two maximal chains of cardinality $\aleph_1$ are order isomorphic.

On a related notes, you can look up the notion of Hardy fields (see for instance the first pages of the article [*On numbers, germs, and transseries*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.06936)), which are chains with a structure of differential field. In particular, you may be interested in maximal Hardy fields.